# Where is the Haskell (.:) operator defined?

Tags: haskell, operators

Apparently the common name for the `((.).(.))` operator is `(.:)`. Where is `(.:)` defined? Or do I have to define it myself?

Comment: Note that [FP Complete's Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=.%3A&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09) is extremely helpful in these scenarios.

Comment: If you have the code which uses some name and successfully loads into the `ghci` or `cabal repl`, you can, for instance, type `:i .:` to get some info about it.

Answer (score 8):

You can find it in the [composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html) library, along with other higher order function compositions.  This operator is not defined in `base`.  If you don't want to add a (very small) package as a dependency then just define it yourself, although I would use the more generalize version that uses `fmap`:

```
(.:) :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
(.:) = fmap fmap fmap
```

which just `fmap`s a function through two layers of functors.  For functions, all three of these `fmap`s specialize to `(.)`.

Comment: Nice take on `.:`. Looks actually more useful for other functors than for functions.